# Lua : Fetch a webpage

Tags: http, networking, lua, html, fetch

I want to fetch a webpage and get the result in a string, but I don't know how to do it. I search online and didn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd simply use [Lua Socket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket) which comes with an [http submodule](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html). You can simply use http.request to get a webpage into whatever container you'd want (default is string, but you can use a table, a file, stdio, ... using ltn12 filters and sinks).

As an example:

```
local http=require'socket.http'
local body, statusCode, headers, statusText = http.request('http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html')
print('statusCode ', statusCode)
print('statusText ', statusText)
print('headers ')
for index,value in pairs(headers) do
    print("\t",index, value)
end
print('body',body)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find an exact http client library, you could implement on yourself, or build on [someone else's work](http://www.steve.org.uk/Software/lua-httpd/).

In that link, although it is called libhttpd, but the author clearly states that it can be used for anything.  Looks like a more usable wrapper around lua sockets.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't have socket (like me), but you have the http library/module, then you could try this:

```
http.get("https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/http/", nil, function(code, data)
    if (code ~= 200) then
        print("HTTP request failed")
    else
        print(code, data)
    end
end)
```

it works for me

you can find more info in the docs https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/http/#httpget

Comment: @dns you need to have the _http_ module on your node

Comment: != isn't a valid Lua operator

Comment: @dns ohh, my bad, it should be `~=`