# How can I take this text and store it in a variable?

Tags: lua

I'm not sure if I can accomplish this with Lua, but I want to take the data from the following URL:

http://www.roblox.com/Trade/InventoryHandler.ashx?token=%22&filter=0&userid=1210210&page=1&itemsPerPage=14&_=

and store it in a variable so I can manipulate it.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lua : Fetch a webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858500/lua-fetch-a-webpage)

Comment: http.request(link) is returning "200 table: 00613E58 HTTP/1.1 200 OK", but I want the actual text at the URL

Comment: @user3314993 `http.request` returns multiple values.

Answer (score -1):

To save a string as a variable it is as simple as

```
foo = "contents of string"
```

To manipulate the string, you would use the [string library](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial)

If you want the text at the URL instead of in the url, see the link to the previously asked question I added in the comments

Comment: If you want the data contained in the link, see this already asked question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858500/lua-fetch-a-webpage)

Comment: I'm trying to get the text at that URL